# Is there a way to group notifications using expo notification

Tags: notifications, expo

expo SDK version: 4.22
expo notification SDK Version: 3.7
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android, iOS

I am using Expo notifications for my app [it is expo managed app] and notification is generated whenever a user send message to another user - like Whats App or any other chat application. Currently, separate notification is displayed for every single message being sent however I would like to group the notification so that in case a user send multiple messages, the receiver device will show grouped notification.

For example,
user A sends 3 messages to user B - “Hi”, “How are you?”, “Hope everything is well”
user C sends 2 messages to user B - “Hello”, “You are at home?”
Expectation is: user B should see 2 grouped notification: (1) from user A showing “3 new messages” (2) from user C showing “2 new messages”.
And when user B expands any grouped notification, then the actual notification should be displayed.

I have tried below in App.json, but it only shows expand-collapse button while each notification is still separated.
“notification”: {
“androidMode”: “collapse”,
“androidCollapsedTitle”: “#{unread_notifications} new messages”
}

Is there a way to achieve this with expo notifications?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!